# Strech the background image to canvas size with Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, css, html, fabricjs

I am using `Fabric.js` and `Canvas` to design some cards. I need to strech the background image to the canvas size. But it is not working. Below is my code.

**SCRIPT**

```
    <script src="/fabric/dist/fabric.js"></script>
    ...
    <script>
    function myBg(){
      var canvas =  this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('myCanvas');

        canvas.setBackgroundImage('images/download.jpg', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), 
        {
            backgroundImageOpacity: 0.5,
            backgroundImageStretch: true
        });

        //this.__canvases.push(canvas); this gives me 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined'
        canvas.renderAll();
    }

    </script>
```

**HTML**

```
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="544px" height="682px">
    <div id="Layer4"  onclick="myBg();"><img src="images/Layer4.png"> </div>
```

It is loading the image but not streching! Any clues?

Comment: what version of fabric.js are you using? because `backgroundImageStretch` is deprecated as of 1.3.9.

Comment: you may need to use [`fabric.Image`](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-1/#images) instead

Comment: They have given an example in their documentation here http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#setBackgroundImage. You can look at one where background image width/height correspond to canvas width/height. I believe this is what you need.

Comment: @Niddro Don't use canvas tag with fabric.js. None of the code for fabric.js can be used directly with a canvas element (even if fabric uses canvas internally, and uses the same term).

Comment: @KenFyrstenberg We were actually editing the same question at the same time; you took the tags away while I  just added the Fabric.js to the title and tags. When I submitted my changes I unintentionally un-did your removal of the non-applicable tags. Good that you saw and removed them once more.