# Fit the background image to canvas size with Fabric js

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to stretch the background image so it can fit the canvas size. But its not working.

I have followed this question and based on comment i have implemented the stretching code.

[Strech the background image to canvas size with Fabric.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29005435/strech-the-background-image-to-canvas-size-with-fabric-js)
http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#setBackgroundImage

## Code

```
$(function () {     
    var canvas1 = new fabric.Canvas('canvas1');
            //Default
    var canvas = canvas1;

    //Change background using Image
    document.getElementById('bg_image').addEventListener('change', function (e) {
        canvas.setBackgroundColor('', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
        canvas.setBackgroundImage(0, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
        var file = e.target.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (f) {
            var data = f.target.result;
            fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function (img) {
                img.set({
                    width: canvas.getWidth(), 
                    height: canvas.getHeight(), 
                    originX: 'left', 
                    originY: 'top'
                });
                canvas.setBackgroundImage(img, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
                /*canvas.setBackgroundImage(img, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
                    width: canvas.getWidth(),
                    height: canvas.getHeight(),
                    originX: 'left',
                    originY: 'top',
                    crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
                });*/
            });
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
});
```

It seems that it is not working with latest beta version, however its working with 1.7.19 version but not with 2.0.0-beta.7

JSFiddle: 
version 2.0.0-beta.7:  http://jsfiddle.net/dhavalsisodiya/8vLo882n/3

varsion 1.7.19: http://jsfiddle.net/dhavalsisodiya/8vLo882n/4/

Comment: issue in 2.0 beta i guess,its working in previous version

Comment: @Durga Yes, correct. I am using latest version to use IText feature.

Comment: Reported this issue on github: https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/4427

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*The [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/8vLo882n/6/) given by [@spankajd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3580933/spankajd) is almost there but still not 100% accurate (as you'll see the background image doesn't completely fit to the canvas).*

The proper solution to this problem is indeed to use the [**`scaleX`**](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#scaleX) and [**`scaleY`**](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#scaleY) property *(which takes a number as scaling factor)*, as mentioned by [@asturur](https://github.com/asturur) on your submitted [issue](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/4427).

However, in that case you won't need to set the **`width`** and **`height`** property of the image. Also, a better (and correct) way of setting those image properties is to pass them as options *(argument)* to the [**`setBackgroundImage()`**](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.StaticCanvas.html#setBackgroundImage) method *(this may resolve some performance issues)*, as such :

```
canvas.setBackgroundImage(img, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
   scaleX: canvas.width / img.width,
   scaleY: canvas.height / img.height
});
```

... instead of setting them for the image object separately.

that being said, here is a complete working example :

```js
$(function() {
   var canvas1 = new fabric.Canvas('canvas1');
   //Default
   var canvas = canvas1;
   canvas.backgroundColor = '#34AD39';
   canvas.renderAll();
   //Change background using Image
   document.getElementById('bg_image').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
      canvas.setBackgroundColor('', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
      canvas.setBackgroundImage(0, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
      var file = e.target.files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(f) {
         var data = f.target.result;
         fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function(img) {
            canvas.setBackgroundImage(img, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
               scaleX: canvas.width / img.width,
               scaleY: canvas.height / img.height
            });
         });
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.0.0-beta.7/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="margin-top:20px;">
   <label class="control-label">Add Background Image</label>
   <input type="file" id="bg_image" />
</div>

<canvas id="canvas1" width="600" height="400" style="border:1px solid #000"></canvas>
```

Comment: This "stretches" the image and doesn't keep aspect ratio. Any tips for maintaining ratio?

Comment: @Grunt : This actually dont follow image aspect ratio. Do you have solution for that?

Comment: This is working fine but in the case of change background image colors, it shrinks the image to a small size. please check the code here 
https://jsfiddle.net/kantsverma/gczk4hqb/23/

Comment: hi , why you are not replying to these question ? your solution is good but this stretch the image and give incorrect pixels value

Answer (score 5):

Hi please update following code.

```
img.set({
           width: canvas.getWidth(), 
           height: canvas.getHeight(), 
           originX: 'left', 
           scaleX : canvas.getWidth()/img.width,   //new update
           scaleY: canvas.getHeight()/img.height,   //new update
           originY: 'top'
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8vLo882n/6/

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to fill the whole canvas without worrying about aspect ratio, see GRUNT's excellent answer. If you want to keep aspect ratio, try the following:

```
function SetImageToBackground(img) {
        let scaleRatio = Math.min(canvas.width / img.width, canvas.height / img.height);
        canvas.setBackgroundImage(img, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
            scaleX: scaleRatio,
            scaleY: scaleRatio,
            left: canvas.width / 2,
            top: canvas.height / 2,
            originX: 'middle',
            originY: 'middle'
        });
    }
```

If you want it to fill the canvas completely, change `Math.min` to `Math.max`.

Setting `left`, `top`, `originX` and `originY` centers it; you may not need that.