# How can I draw image which height is equal to canvas height and width is equal to canvas width in fabric.js

Tags: jquery, canvas, fabricjs

I want to draw a image in fabric.js  which height is equal to canvas height and width is equal to canvas width. and i want that my canvas should be responsive. Is this possible??

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
    var can  = document.getElementById('c');
    $('.js_img_feed').click(function (hello) {
        var  hello1 = hello.currentTarget;
        fabric.Image.fromURL(hello1.src, function(img) {
            canvas.add(img.set({ left: 0, top:0 ,width:can.width, height:can.height}))

        })
    })
})
```

Comment: which fabricjs version you are using?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47010467/3551786)

Comment: fabric.js-2.0.0-beta.7

Comment: please tell me how

Comment: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47077721/3551786) is there, you need to set scaleX and scaleY to the image

Comment: replace can.width by can.getWidth() and can.height by can.getHeight()

Comment: Thank you very much.... It's working.....:)