# Load camera captured image as image in fabric.js canvas in ios

Tags: ionic2, fabricjs

I am developing an app using ionic 2. In the app i capture an image using camera and show the captured image as a background on fabric.js canvas.Below is the code

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(this.picture, (function (image) {
  this.canvas.setBackgroundImage(image, this.canvas.renderAll.bind(this.canvas), {
    width: this.canvas.width,
    height: this.canvas.height,
    originX: 'left',
    originY: 'top'
  });
}).bind(this));
```

After capturing the image when i am trying to load that image as background on fabric.js canvas i am getting "Not allowed to load local resource" error.

path of the image saved after camera capture `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/488CA482-F853-410C-8EC1-B9F8EFCBDC5C/Library/NoCloud/1510540780019_image.png`

Can someone please help in figuring out how to load camera captured image as background in fabric js canvas.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47077721/3551786)

Comment: Hello Durga, the problem is not with setting image as background, the issue that i am facing is whenever i capture an image from camera it gets saved into a data directory and from there when i try to load the image its give an error "not allowed to load local resource".