# how to stretch image size to match fabric.Image object

Tags: fabricjs

I am using fabricjs to implement image editing and I try to use a fabric.Image object as the background image of canvas to store the data. And the following is the code:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvasId');
var imageObject = new fabric.Image($originImage);
canvas.add(imageObject);
```

but I found the **$originImage**'s size is much larger than **canvas**' size and also **imageObject**'s size, so the canvas can only show part of the image. I want to know how to stretch the **$originImage** to adapt the **canvas** then **canvas** can display all of the **$originImage**?

Here what I have done

```
$canvas.width = $originImage.clientWidth;
$canvas.height = $originImage.clientHeight;
var fabricCanvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvasId');
// canvas.setFabricCanvas(fabricCanvas);
var imageObject = new fabric.Image($originImage);
// fabricCanvas.add(imageObject);
// fabricCanvas.isDrawingMode = true;
fabricCanvas.setBackgroundImage(imageObject, fabricCanvas.renderAll.bind(fabricCanvas), {
  scaleX: fabricCanvas.width / $originImage.naturalWidth,
  scaleY: fabricCanvas.height / $originImage.naturalHeight
});
```

the upper is my related code and below is the display:

[image]

it is solved, and the previous question is because I resize the $originImage first, so when I input the image src as setBackgroundImage's parameter, it can display normally.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fit the background image to canvas size with Fabric js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47010467/fit-the-background-image-to-canvas-size-with-fabric-js)

Comment: It seems a little different and I try to use their solution and it cannot help.

Comment: That will work. Which version of fabricjs you are using?

Comment: The version is 2.0, I found that the scaleX or scaleY will adjust fabric.Image's size, but not the image itself. So the result is fabric.Image indeed occupy the whole canvas, but the image itself just show some part. ps. image itself means the <img> element.

Comment: `$originImage` is a image element, right?

Comment: yes, it has a larger natrualWidth of 1800, and the canvas' width is only 967, then I get a fabric.Image of 967 width

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For version 2.0 of fabricjs, they have changed the way to handle width/height compared to previous version. If you apply width/height, then it basically crop the image to that particular size compared to the original image size. In order to resize it to a proper size, you have to switch to use scaleX/scaleY like other people have suggested.

For example, I use image.fromUrl to load an image and set it to be the background:

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(imgUrl, function(img) {
  img.set({
    scaleX: currentWidth / img.width,
    scaleY: currentHeight / img.height,
    top: topPosition,
    left: leftPosition
    originX: 'left', originY: 'top'
  });
  canvas.setBackgroundImage(img, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
});
```

where currentWidth/currentHeight can be your canvas size if you want full background or they can be a specific width/height that you want (in my project, I want to do letter-boxed image instead so I set the width and height based on my letter-boxing algorithm), and top/left is the location that you want to place your image in the canvas (leave it none if you want to be full background image). Do not set any width and height since that will crop the scaled image rather than setting the image to be the exact size.

If this does not work, check the backgroundImage object from the canvas and see if its dimension and scale properties are different compared to a manual calculation. If you take a look, you will see the width and height properties are your natural image width and height, but it will have scaleX and scaleY less than 1 if your canvas size is less than the image size or more than 1 if it is bigger.

Also I see you are loading image directly into an image object. That might be different compared to load the data and set it directly using setBackgroundImage.

Answer (score 0):

```
canvas.setBackgroundImage(img, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
  scaleX: canvas.width / $originalImg.naturalWidth,
  scaleY: canvas.width / $originalImg.naturalHeight
});
```

use scaleX,scaleY to resize.

```js
(function() {
  var $originalImg = $('#originalImage')[0];
  console.dir($originalImg)
  var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
  var img = new fabric.Image($originalImg);
  canvas.setBackgroundImage(img,canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),{
   scaleX:canvas.width/$originalImg.naturalWidth,
   scaleY:canvas.width/$originalImg.naturalHeight
  });
})();
```

```css
canvas{
  border-width: 1pz;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.0.0-rc.3/fabric.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id='originalImage'src='http://fabricjs.com/assets/pug_small.jpg'>
<canvas id='c' width=200 height=200></canvas>
```

Comment: I have tried this solution and it doesn't work, I have posted the result screenshot in my answer, and the whole screenshot is the canvas, and the picture only occupy half of canvas, but now the scale is right...

Comment: The pug is being squashed by your algorithm

Comment: @Jackson cause its fitting to width and height of the canvas. not in proportion.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following script to ensure the image is no larger than the canvas width:

```
var aspect = image.width / image.height; //Aspect ratio of image

new fabric.Image(image, {
  scaleX: canvas.width / image.width,
  scaleY: canvas.width / (image.height * aspect)
});
```