# React resize the base64 image and display in canvas background

Tags: reactjs

currently i doing a react sketch and in this sketch is allow user to insert image for drawing. But the problem is when the image height and width is too large it will over the canvas width and height and i have research on how to resize the base 64 image. But until now still not find solution yet. Is there anyone else know the solution?

```
setBackgroundFromDataUrl = (dataUrl, options = {}) => {
    let canvas = this._fc
    let img = new Image()
    img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous')
    img.onload = () =>  canvas.setBackgroundImage(new fabric.Image(img), () => 
    canvas.renderAll())

//assign base64 image
    img.src = dataUrl
}
```

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47010467/fit-the-background-image-to-canvas-size-with-fabric-js

Comment: Thanks, already find the solution, is the fabric version problem